# Wait For Sign till previous person complete his sign

Tags: docusignapi

@docusignapi  docusignapi team, do we have any option which will help me to maintain document sign sequence. Like, I need sign from 3 person. so 2nd & 3rd person should be wait util 1st person complete his sign. same for 3rd person as well like he should wait till 2nd person complete his sign. Please help

i tried exploring in docusign document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By setting a [signing order](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-signing-order). Referred to as the [routingOrder parameter](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/create/#schema__enveloperecipients_signers_routingorder) in the API documentation